# Problema con parametros del constructor . Java

Tags: java

```
CCC cod = new CCC(entidad, oficina);
        CuentaCorriente c = new CuentaCorriente(cod, n, a);//ERROR entidad y oficina no son String para el programa
        c.ingresarSaldo();
        cuentas.add(c);
```

No entiendo el error que me sale, ya que según el error es que el constructor de CCC espera dos String, y tanto entidad com oficina son String.

Este es el error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - constructor CCC in class BANEURO.CCC cannot be applied to given types;
> required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
> found:    no arguments
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

La instancia de CCC la hace bien ya que poniendo un System.out justo despues lo pinta, pero es en la linea en la que tengo el comentario, que no se lo que pasa realmente.

Cuenta corriente extiende de cuenta qu es asi:

```
public abstract class Cuenta implements Serializable{
  
protected CCC cuenta;
protected String nombre;
protected String apellido;
protected double saldo;


public Cuenta(CCC cuent, String nom, String ape)
{
    cuenta = cuent;
    nombre = nom;
    apellido = ape;
    saldo = 0;
}
```

y CCC es asi:

```
public class CCC implements Serializable{

private String entidad;
private String oficina;
private String dControl;
private String numCuenta;

private static String ultimo;//Se debe usar para que no se repitan los numeros de cuenta

public CCC(String ent, String ofi)
{
    //Crear automaticamente el numCuenta
    numCuenta = generarNumCuenta();
   
    entidad = ent;
    oficina = ofi;
    
    dControl = setdControl();

    
}
```

y CuentaCorriente:

```
public class CuentaCorriente extends Cuenta{

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public CuentaCorriente(CCC cuenta, String nom, String ape)
{
    super(cuenta, nom, ape);
}
```

Comment: que es CCC?? como armaste las clases? podes mostrar como son las clases? sin todos los get y set, solo la definicion de la clase y el constructor.. suena raro que el padre reciba una instancia del hijo en el constructor...

Comment: QUé hace ese `generarNumCuenta()`? qué hace `setdControl`?

Comment: generarNumCuenta(): crea un numero aleatorio de 10 digitos.  setdControl: establece los digitos de control de la cuenta, que se calculan por separado pero al final es uno solo.

Comment: He ampliado para que se vea mas la clase CCC, no se si es eso a lo que te refieres @gbianchi

Comment: y la otra? Cuenta?

Comment: eh... si Cuenta extiende CCC, como puede recibir como parametro un objeto de CCC??? cual es el sentido de eso?

Comment: Esque en cuenta, necesito acceder a los atributos de CCC como numCuenta y sino no tengo acceso

Comment: Vale eso ya está solucionado, Cuenta ya no extiende CCC

Comment: Vale, ya está todo correcto, el error al parecer deberia ser por eso de que Cuenta extendia CCC y aun asi recibia CCC como parametro. Ya lo he arreglado. Gracias

Comment: Creo que estas confundiendo que haces al extender una clase.. si la extendes, deberias tener acceso a las propiedades de la clase padre.. el problema es que las pusiste como privadas... tu problema es de ambitos...